# reference for differential $k$-forms being a sheaf on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $k\geq 1$. See a differential $k$-form on $M$ as $\mathfrak{X}(M)\times \mathfrak{X}(M)\times \cdots \times \mathfrak{X}(M)\rightarrow C^\infty(M)$. Let $\Omega^k(M)$ (similarly $\Omega^k(U)$) be the vector space of differential $k$-forms on $M$ (on $U$).

I am looking for a reference that says that, the assignment $U\mapsto \Omega^k(U)$ for open sets $U$ of $M$, is a sheaf on the manifold $M$.

Consider $\Omega^1:\mathcal{O}(M)\rightarrow \text{Vect}$.

Let $U_1, U_2$ be open subsets of $M$ that cover $M$.

Consider $\omega_1\in \Omega^1(U_1)$ and $\omega_2\in \Omega^2(U_2)$ such that, on the intersection $U_1\cap U_2$ they agree; $\omega_1=\omega_2\in \Omega^1(U_1\cap U_2)$.

We need to define $\omega:\mathfrak{X}(M)\rightarrow C^\infty(M)$. Fix a vector field $X:M\rightarrow TM$ on $M$. This restrict to give a vector field $X_1:U_1\rightarrow TU_1$ on $U_1$ and $X_2:U_2\rightarrow TU_2$ on $U_2$

Define $\omega(X):M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as $m\mapsto \omega_1(m)(X_1(m))$ if $m\in U_1$ or define $m\mapsto \omega_2(m)(X_2(m))$ if $m\in U_2$.

This gives a smooth map by gluing property of smooth maps. This construction is a differential $1$-form on $M$. So, $\Omega^1$ is a sheaf of vector spaces on $M$.

Similarly one can show $\Omega^k(M)$ is a sheaf on $M$.

Unless I am missing some obvious step, this would be a sufficiently ok proof.

Can some one suggest some reference that gives a proof that differential forms form a sheaf on the manifold.

Comment: You're probably more likely to find a reference which demonstrates that sections of a vector bundle form a sheaf. Then $k$-forms are a particular instance for the vector bundle $\bigwedge^kT^*M$.

Comment: Given any vector bundle, its  smooth sections form a sheaf.

Comment: Yes, I am ok with that reference as well. I just want some reference so that I don't have to reproduce the proof. :)

Comment: A comment on [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132718/sheaf-of-differential-forms-tangent-sheaf-hartshorne) suggests Warner's textbook as a reference for sheaves on manifolds.

Comment: I have seen Warner book before, and for conformation I saw it just now. I could not find any such  reference.

Comment: It looks like it is not mentioned anywhere in detail. I will just give a proof, instead of a reference...

Comment: some one gave an answer and deleted. I do not remember who it was. In that they have started with a subjective submersion $\pi:X\rightarrow Y$.. I do not think it is surjective submersion condition is necessary.. It is true for any smooth map $X\rightarrow Y$

Comment: This is certainly in Wells’s complex manifolds book, Griffiths/Harris, etc.

Comment: @TedShifrin : Sir, it is mentioned as "Example 1.9" in Well's complex manifold book but not many details are given. It just says differential forms are sections of bundle. So, they form sheaves. I do not fully understand why does many people want to say they are starting with a vector bundle or principal bundle or a surjective submersion when they want to talk about sheaf described by sections.. We can define sections for any smooth/continuous map.. Is it only to make sure no set in the description is empty? Or, is there a different reason?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this requires a reference. You only need to see that smoothness (and continuity) is a *local* property: a map is smooth iff it is smooth in a small enough neighborhood of every point of its domain. So, for smooth forms (or sections of vector bundles) $\omega_1$, $\omega_2$ that agree on their common domain, the form:
$$\omega(x) = \begin{cases}
\omega_1(x)\text{, }x\in U_1\\
\omega_2(x)\text{, }x\in U_2
\end{cases}
 $$
will also be smooth, because, around any point, either $\omega_1$ or $\omega_2$ is smooth. This is in contrast with presheaves of constant or bounded functions, which are not sheaves because the corresponding proprieties are *global*.

The uniqueness of the form $\omega$ that glues $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ is trivial, as for any presheaf of functions.

To address your question in the comments, you can still define sections for an arbitrary smooth map $f:M\rightarrow N$ (as smooth right inverses of $f$), but if $f$ isn't surjective, you won't have any sections. Indeed, for any point $x\in N\setminus\text{Im}f$, $f (s(x))$ cannot equal $x$. Also, there has to be some algebraic structure involved to obtain a sheaf of groups/modules.

Comment: I don't remember if you are the one who wrote the previous answer.. Thanks for the answer. I do know how to do this, as mentioned in the question. It is just that I am looking for a reference so that I don't have to reproduce the proof..

Comment: I agree with "there has to be some algebraic structure involved to obtain a sheaf of groups/modules".

Comment: I don't quite get what you're saying, why do you need a reference to reproduce a proof if you already know it?

Comment: I am saying I am looking for a reference so that I **do not have to** reproduce a proof...

Comment: After you reproduce it for 1-forms? Just replace your definition of $\omega$ with mine and you're done, it will work for any $k$.

Comment: I can see now that you're talking about reproducing it in some lectures notes or smth. Making that explicit from the start would have saved me some time. In any case, if you won't find a reference (I remember I couldn't when I was learning this), I think you should include in the proof why the "gluing propriety of smooth maps" is true (smoothness is a local propriety), as it shows what type of data a sheaf keeps track of.

Comment: ok. Thanks you for suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

See Manifolds, sheaves, and cohomology by Wedhorn, Torsten. Def 8.61 is what you want. Instead of a proof, it is defined as a locally free sheaf.

Premanifold is manifold deleting the condition of being Hausdorff and second-countable. The $\mathcal{T}_M$ means the sheaf associated to the tangent bundle over $M$.
[image: 1]